# Unable to set custom color palette in pandas pie chart, colors keep getting set based on value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a for loop in python that generates many pie charts for different calculations from a dataframe. I want the color labelling between each pie chart for each for loop iteration to be the same, and so I try to set them to the same color palette dictionary.

```
color_mapping = dict(zip(df_pc_region.index, sns.color_palette('Set2')))
plot_colors = [color_mapping[region] for region in df_pc_region.index]

plot = df_pc[geog].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='pie', startangle=90, colors=plot_colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', fontsize=9, pctdistance=0.80, explode=[0.05]*len(df_pc[geog].unique()))
```

And so, for each chart created for each for loop generation, the colors should be labelled the same, regardless of which label gets the higher value, since the "color" parameter is set to "plot_colors".

And yet, I see that with my first two plots from two separate for loop iterations, the color labelling is not consistent, each with the color labels based on value, rather than the name of each category as I intended by setting "color" to "plot_colors". Why might the color labeling here not be registering with the code?

Comment: `sns.color_palette('Set2')` by default gives a list of 6 colors. If you need more, you can use its `n_colors=...` parameter. But be aware that `Set2` has only 8 distinct colors. See  https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html for a list of common color maps.

Comment: You need the index of `df_pc[geog].value_counts(normalize=True)`, not the index of `df_pc_region.index` to calculate `plot_colors`.  It would be useful to assign `df_pc[geog].value_counts(normalize=True)` to a new variable, e.g. `df_geog = df_pc[geog].value_counts(normalize=True)` and `df_geog.plot(kind='pie', colors=[color_mapping[region] for region in df_geog.index], ...)`

Comment: @JohanC this solved it! The color labeling is now as intended, thank you!